# Finding exact regex match for string in column

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

This is my Dataframe:

```
                         entityId  delta_approved_clockout
 (ID: 10)              247333605                      0.0  
  (ID: 20)               36738870                      0.0  
  (ID: 40)             4668036427                      0.0  
  (ID: 50)             1918647972                      0.0  
  (ID: 60)             4323165902                  44125.0  
  (ID: 80)              145512255                      0.0  
 Assigned (ID: 30)       42050340                      0.0  
 Assigned (ID: 40)   130880371376                      0.0  
 Assigning (ID: 30)    1095844753                      0.0  
 Cancelled (ID: 40)        937280                      0.0  
 Cancelled (ID: 80)   16857720813                      0.0  
 Planned (ID: 20)      9060392597                      0.0  
 Planning (ID: 10)   108484297031                      0.0  
 Processed (ID: 70)  133289880880                      0.0  
 Revoked (ID: 50)      2411903072                      0.0  
 Writing (ID: 50)    146408550024                      0.0  
 Written (ID: 60)    139458227923                1018230.0
```

I want the result to only print the exact regex match for '(ID: 10)', using this line my input includes 'Planning (ID: 10)', which is not the exact match I need. These are the summed results:

```
                        entityId  delta_approved_clockout  
last_status                                                
  (ID: 10)             247333605                      0.0  
 Planning (ID: 10)  108484297031                      0.0  

print input_data[input_data['last_status'].str.contains(r'(?<!\S)\(ID: 10\)(?!\S)', na=False)]
```

I have also tried regex codes that gave 0 results such as:

```
print input_data[input_data['last_status'].str.contains(r' ^(\(ID: \d+\))$', na=False)]

print input_data[input_data['last_status'].str.contains(r'^(\(ID: 10\))$', na=False)]
```

Perhaps I don't understand regex thoroughly, what would be the correct way of writing regex? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `r'^\s*(\(ID:\s*\d+\))\s*$'`

Comment: you want to do it only with regex? You can simply do it using datafram slicing like `df=df['last_status' == '(ID: 10)'] `

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/4Cb8as/1 if you don't want capturing groups remove `()`

Comment: df=df['last_status' == '(ID: 10)''  includes:  Planning (ID: 10), I want solely the matches with (ID: 10)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and S.Kablar, your implementations seem to be working. thanks. I'm still struggling understanding the correct use of regex codes. But I guess practice makes perfect. Ty

Comment: @RA I don't think it will include **Planning (ID: 10)** as it only checks for exact match.

Comment: @RA See my answer below with pattern explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
r'^\s*\(ID:\s*\d+\)\s*$'
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ql8C7P/1).

The pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - zero or more (`*`) whitespace chars
- `\(ID:` - a `(ID:` substring
- `\s*` - zero or more (`*`) whitespace chars
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `\s*` - zero or more (`*`) whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the whole line, you could update your regex to [`^\s*\(ID: 10\).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/h3tX1W/1)

To capture `(ID: 10)` in a group, you could try [`^\s*(\(ID:\s*10\)).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/YBAlZ8/1)

Comment: Alternatively, using a positive lookahead: `(?=.*ID: 10)^(.*)$`

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: [`^\s*\(ID:\s10\)[^\r\n]+`](https://regex101.com/r/4Cb8as/2)

Details:

- `^` Asserts position at start of a line
- `\s` matches any whitespace character
- `*` Matches between zero and unlimited time
- `[^]` Match a single character not present in the list
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited time
- `\r\n` Matches a carriage return and line-feed (newline) character

**Python code**:

```
dataframe = """ (ID: 20)              247333605                      0.0  
  (ID: 50)               36738870                      0.0  
  (ID: 40)             4668036427                      0.0  
  (ID: 50)             1918647972                      0.0  
  (ID: 60)             4323165902                  44125.0  
  (ID: 10)              145512255                      0.0  
 Assigned (ID: 30)       42050340                      0.0  
 Assigned (ID: 40)   130880371376                      0.0  
 Assigning (ID: 30)    1095844753                      0.0  
 Cancelled (ID: 40)        937280                      0.0  
 Cancelled (ID: 80)   16857720813                      0.0  
 Planned (ID: 20)      9060392597                      0.0  
 Planning (ID: 10)   108484297031                      0.0  
 Processed (ID: 70)  133289880880                      0.0  
 Revoked (ID: 50)      2411903072                      0.0  
 Writing (ID: 50)    146408550024                      0.0  
 Written (ID: 60)    139458227923                1018230.0 """

def ID(id, data):
        return re.findall(r'^\s*\(ID:\s%s\)[^\r\n]+' % id, data, re.MULTILINE)

ID(10, dataframe) >> ['  (ID: 10)              145512255                      0.0  ']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
input_data = input_data[(input_data['last_status'] == '(ID: 10)')]
```